# curl command with certificates to php SoapClient (BankID)

Tags: php, curl, soap, https

Based on https://www.bankid.com/assets/bankid/rp/bankid-relying-party-guidelines-v2.13.pdf

I have working `curl` command:

```
curl https://appapi.test.bankid.com/rp/v4?wsdl -E --cacert /path/to/BankID_SSL_Root_Certification_Authority_TEST.pem --cert /path/to/ServerCertificate.cer --key /path/to/PrivateKey.key
```

ServerCertificate.cer and PrivateKey.key were extracted from PFX certificate (https://www.bankid.com/assets/bankid/rp/FPTestcert2_20150818_102329.pfx) with `openssl` command.

But I can't make it work with PHP SoapClient:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://appapi.test.bankid.com/rp/v4?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://appapi.test.bankid.com/rp/v4?wsdl"
```

I will appreciate any help here.

Comment: if you dont need this SoapClient thing, whatever that is, this is easy to translate to native php curl_ api. 


$curlh=curl_init('https://appapi.test.bankid.com/rp/v4?wsdl');
curl_setopt_array($curlh,array(
CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE=>'/path/to/PrivateKey.key',
CURLOPT_SSLCERT=>'/path/to/ServerCertificate.cer',
CURLOPT_SSLKEY=> "/path/to/PrivateKey.key",
));
curl_exec($curlh);

i think

Comment: Hi, thank you for yor suggestion.
"SoapClient thing" is http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

Comment: It appears as though you need to provide a certificate just to access the WSDL.  SoapClient doesn't support this, you can only use cert files for the actual SOAP calls.  However you could try downloading the WSDL and save it locally, and use SoapClient to point to the local WSDL file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you guys for your answers.

The solution:

1. `openssl pkcs12 -in FPTestcert2_20150818_102329.pfx -nocerts -out key.pem -nodes`
2. `openssl pkcs12 -in FPTestcert2_20150818_102329.pfx -nokeys -out cert.pem`
3. `openssl rsa -in key.pem -out server.key`
4. Copy 
   `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
   ... 
   -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`
   section from `server.key` and
   `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   ...
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----`
   section from `cert.pem` and put them into new `certname.pem` file.

Then:

```
try {
    $this->client = new SoapClient( $this->wsdl, array( "local_cert" => "/path_to_cert/certname.pem" ) );
} catch (Exception $e) {
    return json_encode( array( "result" => false, "reason" => $e->getMessage() ) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for future people finding themselves with the same BankID problem, Dmitry gave a very good tutorial on how to get the correct certificate, but the code that worked for me required a few more parameters:

```
try {
    $client = new SoapClient('https://appapi2.test.bankid.com/rp/v4?wsdl',
        ["local_cert" => "certname.pem",
         "stream_context" => [
             "ssl" => [
                 "verify_peer" => false,
                 "verify_peer_name" => false,
                 "allow_self_signed" => true
             ]
         ]
     ]);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    return json_encode( array( "result" => false, "reason" => $e->getMessage() ) );
}
```